# Images and links are not working when they are values of json object properties

Tags: javascript, html, json, object, hyperlink

I don't know what is happening, but both my images and links are not working, even after declaring globally!?
if I write the src directly into src then everything seems fine , even alert pops the same url and img src! need help guys!

```
var combo0;
var combo1;
var combo2;
var combo3;
var random;
var images=["../IMAGES/park.jpg","../IMAGES/palace.jpg","../IMAGES/oriental.jpg"]
var weburls=["https://www.royalplaza.com.hk","https://www.caesars.com","http://www.venetianmacao.com/"]


function gethotel(){           // a= check-in b=check-out and c=no-of-rooms

    var arraysofobjects=[

        combo0=[

        ],

        combo1=[
            {hotelname:"The Royal Plaza",purl:"images[0]",rflag:"",weburl:"weburls[0]",description:"Locate"
            ,price:"HKD 1200"},
        ],

        combo2=[
            {hotelname:"The Royal Plaza",purl:"images[0]",rflag:"",weburl:"weburls[0]",description:"Located  drive away."
            ,price:"HKD 1200"},
            {hotelname:"Caesars Palace",purl:"images[1]",rflag:"",weburl:"weburls[1]",description:"Built in 1903, the treatments"
            ,price:"HKD 1900"}
        ],

        combo3=[
            {hotelname:"The Royal Plaza",purl:"images[0]",rflag:"",weburl:"weburls[0]",description:"Located in less ."
            ,price:"HKD 1200"},
            {hotelname:"Caesars Palace",purl:"images[1]",rflag:"",weburl:"weburls[1]",description:"Built in 1903, tatments"
            ,price:"HKD 1900"},
            {hotelname:"The Venetian Hotel",purl:"images[2]",rflag:"",weburl:"weburls[2]",description:"The Vor area."
            ,price:"HKD 2200"}
        ]
    ]

     random=Math.floor((Math.random() * 4));
     return arraysofobjects[random];
}

var object=gethotel();
for(var i=0; i<random;++i) {

    var heading = '<h2>' + object[i].hotelname + '</h2>';
    var description = '<p>' + object[i].description + '</p>';
    var priceho='<h4>' + object[i].price + '</h4>';

    //web url
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var linkText = document.createTextNode("Offical website");
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    a.title = "official website";
    a.href = object[i].weburl;

    var hotel =  '<img src="object[i].purl">' + '<div>'+ heading  + description + priceho + '<a target="_blank" href=object[i].weburl>Official website</a>' +'</div>';
    var str="Details";
    var link=this.str.link("room.html");
    document.getElementById("hotels").innerHTML+=hotel + link;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like is may be because your `weburl:"weburls[0]"` property value has quotes around it. Try it like: `weburl:weburls[0]`.

I assume that you have an array elsewhere in your code named `weburls`, and the above property is *supposed* to be setting the `weburl` property equal to the value of the 0-indexed item in `weburls`.

With the quotes it means after this line `a.href = object[i].weburl;`, `a.href` is literally equal to `"weburls[0]"`. You should be able to perform an inspection on the DOM to confirm this.

**Update**

The code in the `for` loop seems that it could be replaced with this:

```
var heading = '<h2>' + object[i].hotelname + '</h2>';
var description = '<p>' + object[i].description + '</p>';
var priceho='<h4>' + object[i].price + '</h4>';

var hotel =  
    '<img src="' + object[i].purl + '" />' + 
    '<div>' + heading + description + priceho + 
        '<a target="_blank" href="' + object[i].weburl + '">Official website</a>' + 
    '</div>';
document.getElementById("hotels").innerHTML += hotel;
```

Comment: @Dheeraj Yes, there are also other issues with the code toward the bottom too. For instance, you create the anchor tag, but never add it to the DOM. Also, it doesn't appear that the `hotel` variable is being properly created. One moment, I will update my answer.